# Setting jQuery focus

Tags: jquery, focus, focusout

**Problem**

I'm trying to do an effect where a pop-up appears when the user mouses over. The focus is then set on that popup. When the user does a focusout of said pop-up, it disappears.

**Example**

You can view a working example below, but you'll need to login as "testuser" in both usernames and password fields. Hover the login box once logged in and a pop-up will appear to tell you you're already logged in.

http://www.steelfrog.com

I want that pop-up to fade out once the user removed focus from it, since it contains a logout button.

**Currently...**

What I have so far:

```
$('.disabled').hover (
    function () { $('#bubble_logged').fadeIn(300); },
    function() { $('#bubble_logged').focus(); }
    );

$('#bubble_logged').focusout ( function () { $('#bubble_logged').fadeOut(300); } );
```

Apparently, this is not valid, or there's something I'm not grasping properly. I'm very new to jQuery, so enlightenment would be great!

[EDIT] If you have a better way of doing this, I'm all ears by the way!

Comment: Fails at the first hurdle for me... I'm done, I hit enter to log in and nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm, looks like that fails in IE. I can replicate it. I'll get it fixed before I do anything else. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the native javascript `focus()` method. You can't use this directly on a jQuery object because that object doesn't refer to a only a DOM element.

The selector `$('#bubble_logged')` will return a jQuery object that contains all items with an ID of 'bubble_logged'. There should be only one, but jQuery doesn't care. So, we need to find the first (and only) item in this collection. You can do that either by using `$('#bubble_logged').get(0)` or `$('#bubble_logged')[0]`. Once you do that, you have a reference to the DOM element that you were looking for.

So, we add a `.focus()` to move the focus to that element. `$('#bubble_logged').get(0).focus();` Note that this will attempt to focus the #bubble_logged element. If that is a div, it won't do much. If you are trying to focus an element inside that container, you need to call focus on that instead.

For the `.hover()` jQuery method, you are giving it two anonymous functions. The first is the hoverIn event handler and the second is the hoverOut event handler. I believe that you want the popup to fadein, then have the focus set. To do this, put both of those logic pieces in the first event handler.

```
$('.disabled').hover (
    function () { 
        $('#bubble_logged').fadeIn(300, function(){
            //this is executed once the fadein is complete
            $('#bubble_logged')[0].focus();
        }); 
    },
    ...
);
```

Then, when the hoverOut method is called, you probably want to fadeOut the popup. Just add the following.

```
$('.disabled').hover (
    ...
    function () { 
        $('#bubble_logged').fadeOut(300);
    }
);
```

The final script would look like this.

```
$('.disabled').hover (
    function () { 
        $('#bubble_logged').fadeIn(300, function(){
            //this is executed once the fadein is complete
            $('#bubble_logged')[0].focus();
        }); 
    },
    function () { 
        $('#bubble_logged').fadeOut(300);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, while that didn't work out of the box, I can see how you structured all of this.


I was originally trying to set focus to a div, but as you mentioned, that didn't work. I added an ID to the 'logout' link and it worked perfectly after a slightly modified your script. Thank you!


Long story short, issue was caused by trying to grant focus to a div, which I now know is not the way to go.

Comment: From the doc: "The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as <input>. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page." http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write this as:

```
$('.disabled').mouseenter(function()
{
 $('#bubble_logged').fadeIn(300);
 $('#bubble_logged').focus();
}); 

$('#bubble_logged').focusout(function () 
{ 
  $(this).fadeOut(300); 
});
```

alternative: (focus after fadein completes)

```
$('.disabled').mouseenter(function() 
{ 
 $('#bubble_logged').fadeIn(300, function()
 {
   $('#bubble_logged').focus(); 
 });
});  

$('#bubble_logged').focusout(function ()  
{  
  $(this).fadeOut(300);  
});
```

EDIT2:  At times, I have also seen this as:

```
$('#bubble_logged').blur(function ()   
{   
  $(this).fadeOut(300);
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: While the hover works, #bubble_logged still won't remove itself, but I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Note that the focusout and blur differ in the event bubbling to parent.  Try the .blur() instead perhaps?

Comment: Resolved by setting focus to something other than the div (e.g., anchor in this case), but I'll try blue next time rather than focusout. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `focusout` to `blur`.

Comment: Same deal. Even if I click on the pop-up, then click elsewhere to relieve focus it doesn't disappear.